# Orleans unit test: Provider of type <> name Default was not loaded

Tags: c#, unit-testing, orleans

I've got a following problem.
I'm trying to implement unit test for Orleans grain but when starting it cannot find the dataprovider Default. The exception occurs on constructor call. Here is the code:
Unit test class

```
   [TestFixture]
    public class SdxRemindersTest : TestingSiloHost
    {
        public SdxRemindersTest ()
            : base(new TestingSiloOptions
            {
                StartPrimary = true,
                StartSecondary = false,
                SiloConfigFile = new FileInfo("OrleansConfiguration.xml")

            }, new TestingClientOptions {ClientConfigFile = new FileInfo("ClientConfiguration.xml")})
        {
        }

// methods here.........
    }
```

Here is my config file OrleansConfiguration.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<OrleansConfiguration xmlns="urn:orleans">
  <Globals>
    <StorageProviders>
      <Provider Type="NBOOC.Grains.StorageProviders.CustomSqlStorageProvider"
                          Name="Default"
                          Database=""
                          ConnectionString="" />

     </StorageProviders>
    <StreamProviders>
      <Provider Type="Orleans.Providers.Streams.SimpleMessageStream.SimpleMessageStreamProvider" Name="SMSProvider" FireAndForgetDelivery="false"/>
    </StreamProviders>
    <BootstrapProviders>
      <Provider Type="NBOOC.Grains.OrleansApp" Name="OrleansApp"   />
    </BootstrapProviders>
    <SeedNode Address="localhost" Port="22222"/>
    <Messaging ResponseTimeout="30s"/>
    <ReminderService ReminderServiceType="ReminderTableGrain"/>

  </Globals>
  <Defaults>
    <Networking Address="localhost" Port="22222"/>
    <ProxyingGateway Address="localhost" Port="40000" />
    <Tracing DefaultTraceLevel="Warning" TraceToConsole="true" TraceToFile="{0}-{1}.log" PropagateActivityId="false" BulkMessageLimit="1000">
      <TraceLevelOverride LogPrefix="Application" TraceLevel="Verbose3" />

      <LogConsumer>NBOOC.Grains.Utils.LogConsumer,NBOOC.Grains</LogConsumer>
    </Tracing>
    <Statistics MetricsTableWriteInterval="30s" PerfCounterWriteInterval="30s" LogWriteInterval="300s" WriteLogStatisticsToTable="true" StatisticsCollectionLevel="Info"/>
  </Defaults>
</OrleansConfiguration>
```

The error I'm having is this:

> Exc level 0: Orleans.Runtime.OrleansException: Provider of type
>   NBOOC.Grains.StorageProviders.CustomSqlStorageProvider,NBOOC.Grains
>   name Default was not loaded.Please check that you deployed the
>   assembly in which the provider class is defined to the execution
>   folder.
>
> at Orleans.Providers.ProviderLoader`1.ValidateProviders()
>
> at Orleans.Providers.ProviderLoader`1.LoadProviders(IDictionary`2
>   configs, IProviderManager providerManager)
>
> at
>   Orleans.Runtime.Storage.StorageProviderManager.LoadStorageProviders(IDictionary`2
>   configs)
>
> at
>   Orleans.Runtime.Scheduler.SchedulerExtensions.<>c__DisplayClassa.<b__8>d__c.MoveNext()

As you can see there is a provider with name Default with fully specified type. The class specified there is accessible as all references are there - I've checked this explicitly, all DLL-s are placed in the same folder as unit test DLL. I've also checked all the versions of Orleans DLL - they are all the same 1.0.10.0 so it's not a version issue.
Does anyone ever faced such thing? Any ideas how to fix it?

P.S.  BTW in case if you'll find it helpful. I've downloaded the Orleans sources and traced the place where exception occurs - there is a ProviderLoader class, it has a dictionary of providers Dictionary but for some reason it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone find it helpful. Root cause and possible solution.
Root cause. The problem occurs because on startup of the test the OrleansRuntime tries to do the following: it gets the location of the assembly and loads all the types from all the DLL-s which it finds in the folder near itself.
The problem occurs because .NET performs the shadow copy and loads not the DLL from your folder (i.e. \MyTestProject\bin\Debug), but from something like this - C:\Users\__User__\AppData\Local\assembly\dl3\L1Q53XP9.XXK\Y5C28WBO.YKY\ - there are folders for each DLL. But as we can see there will be no DLL-s (your grains) there (as well as Orleans DLLs for MemotyStorage for example) so the load will fail.
Possible solution is to somehow disable this shadow copying - for example it could be setting  in the web.config. 
But for unit tests still didn't manage to do this. Continue searching.

Comment: You need to specify the deployment items that get copied to the TestResults out folder  (at least thats true of mstest)